# Crystal report Viewer is no working after Publishing the WPF app and running it in another Machine

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, crystal-reports

Report is working fine when I run the application on my development machine.if I run the application on another machine the application gets force closed. the crystal report can't load cause of the missing DLL's  install the crystal report in the testing machine made the app working. I'm not sure what all DLL's are required for Running the viewer

Comment: Which viewer (code), which version/DLL does the viewer come from, what is the error, where are all required details to be able to answer anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not chase missing dlls. Depending on which version of the SDK/runtime you used in the development of your WPF application, you'll need to install the runtime on your target machine. They can be found at the [SAP](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) site. Or for the version 13 downloads named `CRforVS_redist_install_XXX`, directly from [here (version 13 32bit)](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_20.zip) and [here (version 13 64bit)](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_20.zip)